# Backport locale to earlier Windows version

Tags: windows, localization

I have written an application which contains language files localized in `ru-MD` (Russian as used in Moldova) and `ru-RU` (Russian as used in Russia).

According to [this table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx), the locale `ru-MD` is supported in Windows 10/Windows Server 2016 and above. I, however, need to install my application on a Windows Server 2012. As expected, a `CultureNotFoundException` is thrown when trying to run my application on Windows Server 2012.

I know that I can create and install a custom locale using tools such as [MS Locale Builder](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41158), but I'm not an expert in variants of the Russian language (I don't speak the language at all).

Thus, I'd prefer to "backport" or copy the locale from a newer Windows system to the target system. Is that possible and/or supported? If yes, how?